# How many resubmits of my thesis support paper can I expect from my sponsor and readers?

Tags: thesis

I'm preparing a support thesis paper for an aesthetic creation for my MFA. How may times can I expect my sponsor and readers to send my paper back to me for edits?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no fixed answer here. Some advisors are willing to look at drafts in progress and pitch in a lot, while others only want to see almost finished drafts. Committee members beyond the advisor would probably only want to see one or two drafts to edit. Further, their comments will be more high-level than in depth.

But the best way to make sure is to ask!